# remove unwanted text with function and for loop

Tags: r, list, function

I have a list of text strings, and wish to remove selected lines containing unwanted text. I would ultimately like to apply this to a large vector of complex unwanted text, so would like to create reg-expression vector of unwanted items, and a remove function with a for loop. However, running into a problem

```
# create food list
food <- list("apples, watermelon and peaches", "onions and broccoli", "peaches, nectarines", "rutabega")

#create vector of unwanted foods with text pattern
unwanted_foods <- c(unwanted1 = "(.*occol.*)", unwanted2 = "(.*tabe.*)")

# remove list items containing broccoli (works)
food <- str_replace(food, unwanted_foods[1], "")

# trying to work with function (doesn't work)
remove_unwanted1 <- function(mylist){
  mylist <- str_replace(mylist, unwanted_foods[1], "")
}
```

Not sure why the second approach does not work. Eventually want to loop over all items in unwanted_items, something like:

```
remove_unwanted2 <- function(mylist){
  for (i in 1:length(unwanted_foods)) {
    mylist <- str_replace(mylist, unwanted_foods[i], "")
    return(mylist)
  }
}
```

This does remove the first unwanted item in mylist (why only the first one?) but does not update food.

Comment: Use `c(...)`, not `list(...)`, so you end up with a character vector, not a list.

Comment: My real starting text is extracted from multiple PDFs and comes out in list format, so I have to start from there. Maybe I could change that file to vectors but not really sure how to do that as there are thousands of lines.

Comment: If everything inside is a string, call `unlist()` on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach using base functions. I agree that you should just collapse the unwanted strings into a single character. I think the for loop is a little unneeded here and is leading to some of your return problems as pointed out by @wusel.

```
# create food list
food <- list("apples, watermelon and peaches", "onions and broccoli", "peaches, nectarines", "rutabega")

unwanted_foods <- paste(unwanted_foods, collapse = "|") # collapse to single character vector

foods <- lapply(food, function(x) {
  out <- x[!grepl(pattern = unwanted_foods, x = x)] # subset each list item
  return(out)
})
# returns a list of same length as input. Removed foods are now an empty character string
# Filter out empty lists
foods <- Filter(length, foods)
```

Comment: Almost there except the output is only the unwanted foods, rather than the opposite. Seems like adding a "!" somewhere might do it but still thinking about the code.

Comment: To negate the values you would add the `!` in front of the `grep` command and actually you want a `grepl` instead. Editing answer to address your comments @marcel

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve all your problems. Check the comments

```
remove_unwanted1 <- function(mylist){
  mylist <- str_replace(mylist, unwanted_foods[1], "")
  # you need to return it
  return(mylist)
}
remove_unwanted1(food)


remove_unwanted2 <- function(mylist){
  for (i in 1:length(unwanted_foods)) {
    mylist <- str_replace(mylist, unwanted_foods[i], "")
  }
  # return outside of the loop. Otherwise, return is called in the 
  # firt iteration and the function stopps since nothing after return
  # is executed
    return(mylist)
} 
remove_unwanted2(food)

# just check all patterns at once
str_replace(food, paste0(unwanted_foods, collapse = "|"), "")
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help with the functions and loops!